# Is there a reason I cannot access the "Modified By" (Editor) Field in a SharePoint ListItem Object using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

When attempting to access the Modified By field in SharePoint in C# I'm receiving a weird error stating that the property or field has not been initialized. When I use the debugger to drill down, I can see that the Editor field is not in the collection. What's weird is that when I try to get the same item from the same list (based on ID) I am able to access the field.

Setting the stage:

```
 string siteUrl = @"https://sharepointsite";
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

 List qsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SharePointList");
 context.ExecuteQuery();

 User theUser = context.Web.EnsureUser("SharePointUser");
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Get item by ID (this works). When I view the collection in my Locals Window I can see the Editor Key/Value pair.

```
 ListItem item = qsList.GetItemById(1);
 context.Load(item);
 context.ExecuteQuery();
 FieldUserValue editor = (FieldUserValue)item?["Editor"];
 Console.WriteLine(editor.LookupValue);
```

Get ListItemCollection with a CamlQuery passed to GetItems method of the List object. This does not work and when I view in Locals Window I can see that there is no Key/Value pair in the ListItem for "Editor" for the ListItem with the same ID value.

```
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(10);
   

ListItemCollection qsItems = qsList.GetItems(query);
        
context.Load(qsItems);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem listItem in qsItems)
{
     Console.WriteLine(listItem);
     FieldUserValue editor = (FieldUserValue)listItem?["Editor"];
     Console.WriteLine(editor.LookupValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgive one step: In your code that you want to request the User Field, you need another context.Load() for FieldUserValue object, like this:

```
FieldUserValue editor = (FieldUserValue)listItem?["Editor"];
context.Load(editor);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please, try this an give a feedback.

Comment: Hi Antonio, unfortunately this doesn't work. The exception that is being hit in the code is on that first line there, so I still run into it. I should have made that clear in my original post, my apologies. 

I may be able to follow your general line of thinking and load the ListItem and run execute query again, but for a list that is thousands of lines long this seems like a lot of back and forth. What's odd is that the rest of my fields (even lookups) do return values.

Comment: @BrendanMahoney, here on StackOverflow it is very important to write the requirements question as detailed as possible, so the community returns with a correct answer. Really, it was necessary to mention the 'list that has thousands of lines' in the opening question. The answer to your new requirements: If you want to consume list with more than 5000 items into your C# code, you'll need to use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) with pagination.